# how to push data from an Arduino pin to Bluetooth module

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

I'm writing a software that can receive data from Arduino via Bluetooth. My software is pretty fine now, at least it can pair with my hardware but when I try to test whether it can receive data via Bluetooth, I'm stuck. My Arduino receives temperature readings from a sensor at Analog pin 0. My Bluetooth module HC-05 connects with Arduino at Digital 0 and 1 (RX and TX pin respectively, as default). I don't know how to push data from Analog pin 0 to the Bluetooth module. Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: You don't. You send a message via Bluetooth that the pin has changed.

Comment: Sorry, could you give me more explanation, Ignacio?

Comment: Let's start simple. How would you do it if you were using the serial connection?

Comment: You meant if the Analog pin 0 is HIGH, set TX pin of Arduino HIGH?

Comment: you will need to read this http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print And you might want to try some of the basic tutorials you can find online or a book on starting arduino.

Answer (score 1):

The HC-05 looks like like any other terminal to the Arduino so any serial operations that you would use for a wired terminal can be used with the HC-05. See the HC-05's manual for how to set it up initially. Note that HC-05s don't forget their settings and they have no reset command to put them into a known state, so write down your settings for your future reference.

```
- Read the analog pin value;
- Convert the value into whatever physical units you require;
- Print the result with Serial.print() or Serial.println()
```

Edit:  You wrote that your HC-05 is connected to Digital 0 and 1, but you created your SoftwareSerial, `mySerial`, to transmit on Digital 11. In that case your HC-05's receive pin must be connected to Digital 11.

Comment: While this is correct, the asker has no idea how to perform serial operations.

Comment: Tks guys. I know how to convert my readings into Celcius values and print the result on Serial Monitor by Serial.print but I wonder whether I should convert my readings into bits (I mean analog-digital conversion) before pushing them into the Rx pin of Hc-05; as abovementioned, my sensor is connected to an analog pin while hc-05 is connected to 2 digital pins.

Comment: If you're trying to send the readings as text via Bluetooth, just as you would to a wired terminal, you don't need to do anything but replace the serial cable with the HC-05. It is designed to look to the Arduino like a serial terminal.

Comment: Could you look at my codes above and tell me if anything wrong, JRobert? I assume I connected HC-05 to Arduino correctly because I watched and followed exactly some tutorials on Arduino and HC-05.

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistakes in the code. Have you tried the suggestion in my edit, above? Have you tried replacing the HC-05 with a serial cable to make sure your codes transmits what you expect?

Answer (score 0):

It's my code. Can anyone suggest anything wrong with it if my idea is to push data from Analog pin 0 to Digital pin 11, which is the Tx pin on Arduino connecting to Rx pin on HC-05?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); 
int tempPin=0;

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
mySerial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{ 
 float reading = analogRead(tempPin); // reading on tempPin        
 float voltage = reading*5.0/1024.0; // the resolution of a pin is 10 bit,
 float tempC = voltage/0.01; // 10mV = 1 Celcius 
 mySerial.write(tempC);

 delay(3000);
}
```

Comment: looks ok to me. doesn't it work?

Comment: You're using `mySerial.write()` which will send *binary* data down the serial line.  Were you expecting text?  Maybe try mySerial.println().